# Помогите создать numpy массив

Tags: python, numpy, обработка-данных

Помогите создать numpy массив из 100 элементов (от 1 до 100), переформатировать в формат (10 * 10), сделать слайсинг с шагом 2 по каждой оси? В итоге должно получиться:

```
array([[1,  3,  5,  7,  9],
       [21, 23, 25, 27, 29],
       [41, 43, 45, 47, 49],
       [61, 63, 65, 67, 69],
       [81, 83, 85, 87, 89]])
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: @Jack_oS, можно проголосовать за закрытие вопроса - это более действенная мера ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(1, 101).reshape((10, 10))[::2, ::2]

print(arr)
```